# Ansible fact setting using set_fact not persisting across runs

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to understand just how set facts would help me to create "facts" on the fly that I can then use in subsequent runs. To that end I've created this simple YAML to try it out. It isn't behaving the way I thought. Here it is:

```yaml
- name: record updated mysql root password
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: setting a new fact
      set_fact:
        pwd_updated: True
        cacheable: yes
```

This runs all fine. However when I try to see if a new fact got added using the `setup` module, it isn't there

```bash
ansible all -m setup -i inventory > ~/ansible_localhost.facts
```

On running the above command and checking out `ansible_localhost.facts` I cannot find my new 'fact' viz. `pwd_updated`. Am I doing something wrong?

---

**UPDATE1**

I've followed @VladimirBotka 's advice and now it works just like I wanted.

However I've now enhanced my code (or is it called a script?) such that I now want it to set the fact *only* if it is not already set. In case it already is, should skip the task and execute the next debug task which should *only* be executed if the fact is set and *not* otherwise. Here's the updated code:

```yaml
- name: record updated mysql root password
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: setting a new fact
      set_fact:
        pwd_updated: True
        cacheable: yes
      when: mysql_root_pwd_updated is undefined
    - debug: 
        var: pwd_updated
      when: mysql_root_pwd_updated is defined
```

Running for the first time gives:

```yaml
Using /home/ansible/DevOpsPractice/DevOpsScripts/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [record updated mysql root password] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [setting a new fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"pwd_updated": true}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => {}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Running for the second time gives exactly the same:

```yaml
Using /home/ansible/DevOpsPractice/DevOpsScripts/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [record updated mysql root password] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [setting a new fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"pwd_updated": true}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => {}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What am I doing wrong this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a "fact" added by the `setup` module (which is run by `gather_facts: yes`), add them to the custom facts in `/etc/ansible/facts.d/*.fact` files.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#facts-d-or-local-facts

Use the `copy` module, or `template` or `lineinfile`, to create those files.
https://medium.com/@jezhalford/ansible-custom-facts-1e1d1bf65db8

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure a [cache plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins). See what cache plugins are available

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t cache -l
```

For example, put the cache into JSON formatted files. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t cache jsonfile
```

and configure the plugin

```ini
shell> grep fact_caching ansible.cfg
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache.json
fact_caching_prefix = ansible_facts_
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

Then, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        pwd_updated: True
        cacheable: yes
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1]
ok: [host_2]
ok: [host_3]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and creates the cache at the controller

```bash
shell> ls -1 /tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_host_*
/tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_host_1
/tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_host_2
/tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_host_3
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_cache.json/ansible_facts_host_*
{
    "pwd_updated": true
}{
    "pwd_updated": true
}{
    "pwd_updated": true
}
```

The next play will read the cache automatically

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: pwd_updated
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  pwd_updated: true
ok: [host_2] => 
  pwd_updated: true
ok: [host_3] => 
  pwd_updated: true

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: your solution works like a charm. However I've updated my code (script??) to conditionally set the fact _only_ if it not already set. But that doesn't seem to work as expected. Are there any gotchas or caveats that I need to be aware of?